# How to get the value of a Range given an index in Swift

Tags: swift, swift3

Given the following range declaration and usage in Swift 3:

```
let values = [1...50]

cell.textLabel?.text = String(values[indexPath.row]! + 1)
```

How could do something like the above where I could cast the value of an item at a specific index to a String?

Comment: Couldn't get you? Can u share what input will you give and what output do you want!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make `values` be an array of `Int` from `1...50` you can use:

```
let values = Array(1...50)
```

then you can use the values like this:

```
cell.textLabel?.text = String(values[indexPath.row])
```

---

To make `values` be an array of `String` from `"1"` to `"50"` use:

```
let values = (1...50).map(String.init)
```

then you can do:

```
cell.textLabel?.text = values[indexPath.row]
```

Comment: That's perfect. Thanks!